# Makefile for Fortran gives this error: make: don't know how to make datastructures.o

Tags: makefile, fortran, gfortran, freebsd

I am trying to prepare my first makefile for Fortran:

My code is so far separated in three object modules.

This is my makefile:

```
# Variables

OBJS=datastructures.o global.o main.o
FC=/usr/local/bin/gfortran8
FFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc8

# Makefile

test1: $(OBJS) 
        $(FC) -o mktpro_a $(FFLAGS) $(OBJS)

%.o: %.f90
        $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $<

clean:
        rm $(OBJS)
        rm test1
```

But I get the following error:

```
$ make test1
make: don't know how to make datastructures.o. Stop
make: stopped in /usr/home/user/marketprofile
```

I am using FreeBSD12 and gcc8 (gfortran8)

Comment: Try to use `gmake` (GNU make).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps other people, this seems the way to implement this in FreeBSD 12 make (which seems to be PMake).

```
.SUFFIXES       : .o .f90
.f90.o          :
        $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $(.IMPSRC)
```

More info here: [ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/misc/lite2-docs/psd/12.make.ps.gz](http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/misc/lite2-docs/psd/12.make.ps.gz)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
%.o: %.f90
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $<
```

change it to

```
.f90.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) $<
```

You might need an explicit output too (I am not familiar with this compiler):

```
.f90.o:
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, i have added both options but unfortunately it does not work. I still have the same message. I have learned that FreeBSD uses PMake. I am reading ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/misc/lite2-docs/psd/12.make.ps.gz and trying to figure out how to achieve this. If I rename the .f90 to .f it works (it seems that the rule to construct .o from .f is already implemented)

Comment: `.SUFFIXES       : .o .f90
\n .f90.o          :
        $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $(.IMPSRC)` apparently this works (read \n as an additional line)